# Why are my P&T Assets folders taking 2 minutes to load?

Tags: assets, loading-time

I am using Assets to manage some of the images on my site. The CP loads as expected and nothing is too out of the ordinary. I have 196MB RAM set in PHP.ini and on a VPS.

When I click on an assets folder, the more images I have in there the longer it takes to load, which isnt so far-fetched, but it is taking around 2 minutes to load a folder with about 60 images in it. That same folder locally takes < 5 seconds.

What can be causing this? Here is a screenshot of a XHR report.
[image]

Comment: Can you select the correct answer below?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the difficulty here was a very large number of folders and sub-folders.  Condensing the folders down has sped up the load significantly and are working on improvements in that area for the future of Assets.

Thank you!

-Lisa Wess
Pixel & Tonic

Comment: We were able to remove many files and folders, for now. But there will be a total of 300+ subdirectories as our data begins to get implemented. So while there hasn't been a full solution, we have been able to narrow down that, indeed, there are too many files and folders for the current iteration of Assets to handle in a timely manner on our server. 

We are going to be testing a solution provided by Lisa and P&T, which already sounds like it will be the answer to the problem we are experiencing.

Thanks Lisa!

Comment: My pleasure, Wedodan!